# Confused with Object references in two different cases

Tags: java, object, reference, linked-list

Consider the following example.

```
    Employee emp = new Employee();

    emp.name="John";
    emp.id=3;

    Employee emp2=emp;

    System.out.println(emp.toString());    // prints 3 John
    System.out.println(emp2.toString());   // prints 3 john

    emp2.name="Cena";
    emp2.id=9;

    System.out.println(emp.toString());     //prints 9 Cena
    System.out.println(emp2.toString());    //prints 9 Cena here whatever changes made to emp2 are refletced in emp object too
```

Now example 2(for Inserting a node at the tail of linked list):

```
 static Node Insert(Node head,int data) {   
     Node head1=new Node();   // New node for insertion
     head1.data=data;
     head1.next=null;

     if(head==null) {        
         head=head1;     
         return head;
     }
     else {
         Node tmp=head;   // here both tmp and head needs to be same always as in the previous exaample
         while(tmp.next!=null) {
             tmp=tmp.next;// but head and tmp are not equal after an iteration why...?
         }
         tmp.next=head1;        
         return head;
     }    
 }
```

Cant understand the difference between both scenarios as both cases seems to be the same.
Can someone explain...?

Comment: Because you are reassigning `tmp` using `tmp=...`. Note that `emp2.name=...` is not reassigning `emp2`, it's actually reassigning `emp2.name`...

Comment: @wijaya no actually.. trying to be one :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, when you say `emp2=emp` you've basically said "I want emp2 to point to the same memory block as emp" So, they are both pointing to the same memory. If you change that memory, they'll both fetch that same block and both reflect the change.

The second example does the same thing. However, you are updating the reference in the second one without updating the other. When you say `tmp = tmp.next` you update it to point to a new memory location. However, `head` does not get such an update. Thus, they will be different values.

So, think of it like this:

```
obj1 --> memory0
obj2 --> memory0
```

updating *the values* of one of these will update *the values* both. But...

```
obj3 --> memory1
obj4 --> memory1
obj3 --> memory.next (memory2)
```

Object 3 is now pointing at memory2, but object 4 is still pointing at memory 1.

Comment: I was actually going to say exactly the same. This is the explanation. In Java every Object is a pointer to some place in the actual memory. So your employees variables are pointing to the same memory address. You update the data from one pointer, the other pointer is going to see the new data as well.

Comment: @Araymer thanks.! but may I know how memory.next is memory2().(I mean how temp.next changes memory location) Can I find any  resources where I can find more about how these object references work in a linked list.

Comment: It's not, specifically. The memory allocation isn't that simple (Though, it might be the next sequential block, depending on what's there at the time). But, I just labeled as such for clarity of concept.

As far as Linked Lists, there's tons of google-able stuff. They're a very, very common data structure.

Answer (score 0):

The crucial difference is that in the `Node` example you have two `Nodes`, in the `Employee` example there is only one.

Count how many `new` calls there are.

```
Node head1=new Node();  // new instance
```

In the `Node` example, you receive one instance from outside your method, and you make another one by calling `new`.

```
Employee emp2=emp;     // additional name for existing instance
```

In the `Employee` example, you make one `Employee` (and then assign it to two different variables, but it's still just one object instance).